# React Swiper Slider keep shaking when mouse move to the top of the screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper.js

How to reproduce:

Need to use a MacOS desktop device.

1. Make the slider inside a Modal.
2. Put two images in different sizes into that slider.
3. Open that Modal with a fullscreened window.
4. Move the mouse to the top of the screen, ensure the menu bar shows.

And then the modal starts shaking since the image keeps being resizing, becoming larger and smaller repeatly.

I wonder why this could be happening. Has anyone encountered anything similar?

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/navigation';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';
import { Navigation, Pagination } from 'swiper';
import { FC, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { IRootState } from '@/store';
import { isMobileDevice } from '@/components/contains/contants';

export interface CarouselInstagramProps {
    items?: any[];
}

const CarouselInstagram: FC<CarouselInstagramProps> = ({
    items = [],
}) => {

    const themeConfig = useSelector((state: IRootState) => state.themeConfig);
    const swiperRef = useRef<any>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('items', items);
    }, [items])

    return (
        <div className='w-full CarouselInstagram'>
            
            <Swiper
                ref={swiperRef}
                modules={[Navigation, Pagination]}
                pagination={{ clickable: true }}
                className="swiper mx-auto max-w-3xl w-full"
                id="slider1"
                dir={themeConfig.rtlClass}
                key={themeConfig.rtlClass === 'rtl' ? 'true' : 'false'}
            >
                <div className="swiper-wrapper">
                    {
                        (!items || !Array.isArray(items) || !items.length) &&
                        <SwiperSlide>
                            <img src={'/assets/images/Vertical-Placeholder-Image.png'} className="w-full object-cover" alt="itemImage" />
                        </SwiperSlide>
                    }
                    {
                        items && Array.isArray(items) && items.map((item, i) => {
                            return (
                                <SwiperSlide key={i}>
                                    {
                                        item?.mediaType ?
                                        (
                                            item?.mediaType == 1
                                            ?
                                            // Image
                                            <img src={process.env.BASE_URL + '/general/files/' + item?.mediaUrl?.replaceAll('/', '%2F')}
                                            className="w-full object-cover" alt="itemImage" />
                                            :
                                            // Video
                                            (
                                                isMobileDevice() ?
                                                <img className="w-full object-cover"
                                                src={process.env.BASE_URL + '/general/files/' + items[0].thumbnailUrl?.replaceAll('/', '%2F')} />
                                                :
                                                <video className="w-full object-cover" controls>
                                                    <source src={process.env.BASE_URL + '/general/files/' + item?.mediaUrl?.replaceAll('/', '%2F')} type="video/mp4" />
                                                    Sorry, your browser doesn&#39;t support videos.
                                                </video>

                                            )
                                        )
                                        :
                                        (
                                            item?.type != "video/mp4"
                                            ?
                                            // Image
                                            <img src={URL.createObjectURL(item)}
                                            className="w-full object-cover" alt="itemImage" />
                                            :
                                            // Video
                                            <video className="w-full object-cover" controls>
                                                <source src={URL.createObjectURL(item)} type="video/mp4" />
                                                Sorry, your browser doesn&#39;t support videos.
                                            </video>
                                        )
                                    }
                                </SwiperSlide>
                            );
                        })
                    }
                </div>
                <button onClick={() => swiperRef && swiperRef.current && swiperRef.current.swiper.slidePrev()} id="swiper-button-prev-ex1" className="swiper-button-prev-ex1 absolute top-1/2 z-[999] grid -translate-y-1/2 place-content-center rounded-full p-1 transition ltr:left-2 rtl:right-2">
                    <div className=" _9zm0"></div>
                </button>
                <button onClick={() => swiperRef && swiperRef.current && swiperRef.current.swiper.slideNext()} id="swiper-button-next-ex1" className="swiper-button-next-ex1 absolute top-1/2 z-[999] grid -translate-y-1/2 place-content-center rounded-full p-1 transition ltr:right-2 rtl:left-2">
                    <div className=" _9zm2"></div>
                </button>
            </Swiper>
        </div>
    );
};

export default CarouselInstagram;
```

By the way, the exact same code won't have the issue like this if it is on a page instead of inside a modal.